# How to programmatically capture a payment?

Tags: commerce, 9

Payment is in Authorized state. How do I programmatically capture it? I am using Authorize.net payment gateway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out on my own:

```
function capture_payment($order_id) {
  $order = Order::load($order_id);
  $payment_method_id = $order->payment_method->target_id;
  $payment = getPayment($payment_method_id);
  $amount = new Price($order->total_price[0]->number, $order->total_price[0]->currency_code);

  $gateway = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getStorage('commerce_payment_gateway')->loadByProperties([
      'plugin' => 'authorizenet_acceptjs',
    ]);
  $plugin = $gateway['authorize_net_accept_js'];
  $payment_gateway_plugin = $plugin->getPlugin();

  $payment_gateway_plugin->capturePayment($payment, $amount);
}

function getPayment($method_id) {
  $payments = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getStorage('commerce_payment')
    ->loadByProperties(['payment_method' => $method_id]);
  $payment = current($payments);
  return $payment;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To programmatically capture a payment using the Authorize.Net payment gateway, you will need to follow these steps:

1. Integrate your application with the Authorize.Net payment gateway.
   This will typically involve setting up an account with
   Authorize.Net, and installing their SDK or library in your
   application.
2. Create a payment form in your application that allows users to enter
   their payment details. This form will typically include fields for
   the user's credit card number, expiration date, and security code.
3. When the user submits the payment form, send a request to the
   Authorize.Net payment gateway to initiate the payment. This request
   will include the user's payment details, as well as any other
   relevant information such as the amount of the payment and the
   currency.
4. The payment gateway will process the payment, and send a response
   back to your application indicating whether the payment was
   successful or not. If the payment was successful, you can then
   capture the payment by sending a capture request to the payment
   gateway.

To send a capture request to the Authorize.Net payment gateway, you will need to use the `CaptureOnly` API method. This method requires the following parameters:

`x_trans_id`: The transaction ID of the authorization you want to capture.
`x_amount`: The amount you want to capture.
`x_invoice_num`: An optional invoice number for the capture.
You can find more information on the `CaptureOnly` API method in the Authorize.Net documentation.

Keep in mind that these steps are just a general outline, and the specific details will vary depending on your specific implementation. It's important to consult the documentation and support resources provided by Authorize.Net to get more detailed information on how to use their APIs and functionality.

Comment: Took a while to realize you are not talking abut Drupal. You are talking abut writing this all from scratch. Hopefully there is an answer specific to the existing Auth.net payment gateway (for Drupal).